# How to read, manipulate and write .docx file in c

Tags: c, xml, docx

I am reading .docx file in a buffer and writing it to a new file successfully. (Using fread and fwrite in C) However now I want to enhance the scope of this project for the purpose of encryption. For which I want to be able to manipulate the buffer, then write it in new file.

Now one question might be, what manipulation do I need?
It could be anything really, like I'd write character 's' in buffer's location 15. Like below, and then write this new buffer (having character 's' at location 15, but the rest of the buffer remains unchanged) in a new .docx file.

```
buffer[15] = 's';
```

When I did this, the file that was created was corrupt. Since I am not fully aware of the structure of .docx file, this byte number 15 could be some potential identifier, or header, or any important information of .docx file needed for creating a non-corrupt file.

However, the things I know about .docx internal structure are:

1. It consists of XML files, zipped together.
2. The content that is written in .docx file, (for e.g. I have a file named test.docx, and it contains "Hello, how are you?") then the contents "Hello, how are you?" are stored in XML files.
3. There is a .rels (not confirm) extension file, among those files that are zipped together, that tells MS word about where the content is stored in file, i.e. where to look for content.

Apart from these 3 points I don't know much about structure of .docx file. Now considering all this, I want to be able to extract the contents of .docx file, from the XML files zipped together, read it (in C) in a buffer, change the buffer as I need it, and create a new file, with the new content that is present in the buffer.

Can someone guide me through this? 
Also kindly mention, if I need to provide code, or any other essential details. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

PURPOSE OF ALL THIS:

I want to do all this for encryption. As by encrypting a file (using AES) the whole file will become unreadable, corrupt and everything inside will be changed from its place. When I decrypt that file, the file is unable to open. My guess is, as AES decryption algo does not know how to parse the contents recovered from decrypting the encrypted file, in to a new .docx file, thus it is unable to place the contents/structure properly in its place.

I have tried it. Original docx file was of 14 KB, encrypted docx file was of 14 KB as well as the decrypted docx file. But when I try to open the decrypted file, it says file is corrupt. Also I tried to check it in HEX editor. Decrypted file has just 00 bytes after exactly 30 Bytes.

Comment: What are you __actually__ trying to achieve. This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `docx` documents are supposed to be [OfficeOpen XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) documents, which are standardized. Office is known for adding non-standard extensions to it, and there used to be some controversy about features that were barely documented or not documented at all. I suggest you try to find a library to handle the documents for you, not try to do it all yourself.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I want to read the contents of .docx file in a buffer and add anything I like in that buffer, then use it afterwards to create a new .docx file.

Comment: Do you have any idea about such library? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @alex yes I understood that. But you should explain what the purpose of all this is. Why do you want to add "something" to a Word document. Suppose you manage to add "something" to the word document, then what ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have edited my question now, kindly check it

Comment: @alex I think you're misunderstanding how encryption works - the AES algorithm does not need to understand your file or parse anything. It is bit-level manipulation, nothing more. If your file becomes corrupted along the way, your implementation of the algorithm is wrong.

Comment: @alex This doesn't directly answer your question, but you'll eventually need to parse the .docx file at some point, and that'd involve string manipulation.  Doing *anything* string related in C is a giant PITA and you'll end up debugging unnecessary bugs.  I'd wholeheartedly encourage you to use another language, preferably one that provides first class support for strings.

Answer (score 1):

DOCX files are based on OPC and OOXML.  OPC is based on Zip.  OOXML is based on XML.  Therefore, you can use Zip and XML tools to operate on DOCX files.  Beyond this, you'll have to be more specific about what you wish to do in order to receive better guidance.

Poking characters into random index locations in an XML file is operating at the wrong level of abstraction.